# Clamp meter voltage for 15 amps

Tags: electrical

When using my Clamp meter, i notice that it had a range in the upper 90's instead of 120 on a 14 ga - 15 amp circuit breaker. Is that low or is it because i have close to 20 duplex outlets (for now connected to it-planning to change that). Mostly tv and a computer and outlets and lights. Is that common? And if not why am i getting in the high 90's? Or should you always get between 110-120?
Second questions should there be any voltage in traveler wires in a 3 way 14 ga 15 amp circuit connecting two lights?

Comment: Probably inductive coupling.  Otherwise you're reading through bulb in series.

Comment: What kind of meter did you use and how did you use it? I thought the term "clamp" meter referred to an inductively coupled meter used to measure current. I am not familiar with voltage being measured by a clamp meter.

Comment: Are you sure the meter is good? Are the batteries in the meter fresh?  How exactly are you measuring the voltage (between what points in the circuit)?

Comment: I agree with the above comments 1 more question is your meter a true RMS meter? My clamp meters have probes for measuring voltage is this the type you have? non contact voltage detection is sketchy at best. as far as the travelers yes there should be power present on 1 of the wires but the other may show induced voltages as mentioned above. Check the voltage at the panel I have found some panels FPE & zinsco to have higher than normal voltage drop in the past. 20 outlets is a lot but if not loaded beyond 15 amps the voltage should not drop as far as you are seeing.

Comment: @JimStewart used a klein cl600 clamp meter where you put the wire perpendicular through. It can measure voltage ac and dc and continuity and resistance (rms)

Comment: @Tester101 brand new meter. Brand new batteries. I run the wire perpendicular through as instructed. It is in the middle since it is coming from another room and then proceed to addition rooms. Should it always read 120 regardless how many outlets and fixtures are on it? And if this is 99 what does that tell you?

Comment: I have never heard of *quantitative* measurement of voltage (more properly known as "electric potential difference") other than with probes that contact the conductor.  I am more than willing to be corrected, but my understanding is that if the meter is only clamped around a wire it can measure electric current (amps) flowing through the wire, but not the potential difference (volts) between that wire and neutral or ground. Maybe this clamp has little spikes which pierce the insulation on the wire and make contact with the conductor and the meter is connected to ground? Is that it?

Comment: @larrypinsky You're doing it wrong.  You have to use the probes to test voltage. Please see the [Operating Instructions for the Klein Tools® CL600 (PDF)](http://www.kleintools.com/sites/all/product_assets/documents/instructions/klein/CL600_1390104ART_WEB.pdf).  Specifically, check the [section on measuring voltage](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SHWVX.png)

Comment: @EdBeal yes my clamp meter does have probes? Would that be more accurate and if i get the same reading (99) what should i interpret? Remember i have 20 fixtures and duplex receptacles for now connected to it. It is true rms. So what your saying it could drop and best to get it at the panel?

Comment: If the panel voltage is at 99vac or close to that I would contact the utility they may need to tap up a transformer. In my area below 112vac they will bump the taps to provide at least 112 usually 115vac .

Comment: @jim Stewart there are non contact high voltage meters we use on ultra high voltages 180kv used on ion implanters, I have seen lower voltage models but they are not so good with a loaded circuit so they do exist. Note they do need a ground reference and the measurement is a specific distance from the conductor or corona ball.

Comment: @larry pinsky follow the instructions for the voltage measurement between two points where the (metal) conductor is contacted with two probes. That will be correct. Any non-contact method is either a misunderstanding of the user manual or, if actually allowed, would not be as accurate. With receptacles just stick one probe into the hot (smaller) slot and one into the neutral (larger) slot. My guess is that the reading you are getting with the clamp attachment is indeed a *voltage*, but it is meant to be converted to a current by multiplication by a factor (printed on the current probe?).

Comment: If you look at the readout when using the clamp attachment what are the units displayed? millivolts, mV? Is this reading you are quoting actually 99 mV? If so, you are supposed to multiply, or divide by a factor specific to the clamp coil which has units of A/mV or mV/A, respectively. The 99 figure you are quoting may actually be the Fluke meter telling you the factor for that clamp (99 mV/A) rather than an actual reading. What are you clamping the meter around? the entire cable with black, white and ground? You must clamp around a single wire which can be either the hot or the neutral.

Comment: I have made costly mistakes by misunderstanding situations and on some occasions risked severe injury. Be sure you understand what you are being told. The Klein rep may assume that you are more experienced or trained than you may be. Just sayin' 'cause I bin thar mslf.

Comment: Your absolutely right. They are sending me alligator clips as well. You need to use the probes or alligator clips. The clamp is only for amperage. I feel like an idiot. I should had read the manual. Thank you so very much for pointing this out. Will read the manual tonight and retest it with the probes until they send me the clips shortly. Klein order # 685566.   They will ship tomorrow, you should get them Friday, or Monday.   Best Regards,   Matt Kuhn Customer Service Associate Mkuhn@kleintools.com Direct 847.821.5644 Klein Tools 800-553-4676/4857F. Thank u.

Comment: Larry what do you intend to use the alligator clips on? It is easy to short using the alligator clips.  Most of the time one in residential power situations one uses the spike probes, and uses them carefully. Normally you would insert the probes in a receptacle--one probe in the hot slot and  and one in the neutral slot. **And don't touch the exposed ends of the probes together when they are in the slots and don't touch your hand to the metal of the probes only to the insulated plastic.**

Comment: " probes dont work on tamper resistant [receptacles] except if you use an extension cord. – larry pinsky"  Just so, indeed. I generally use a 2 ft one even when testing standard non-tamper resistant receptacles because once I insert the probes into the cord I can leave them in and just move the cord from receptacle to receptacle. This is a lot easier than jamming the probes into each receptacle.

Comment: Thanks jim. I wanted the alligator clips for voltage to copper wires to test for voltage as well as for continuity (with the power off). Yes I'm aware i could do the same with the regular probes to test for voltage on the copper wires as well. It is just a preference. I used alligator clips before when tracking wires to my circuit breakers. Again only preference. But does it really matter if it is alligator clips or probes? I sis use the probes before i replaced my old receptacles with them as you indicated. And yes i did take your suggestion earlier on using the extension cord which worked.

Comment: @JimStewart your right the Klein rep was talking amperage with the clamps which was my fault. I thought he said voltage. And again your right thoroughly read and understand and ask questions before attempting.

Answer (score 2):

Larry from the online info on this meter

> Klein Tools CL600 is an automatically ranging true root mean square
>   (TRMS) digital clamp-meter that measures AC current via the clamp, and
>   measures AC/DC voltage, resistance, continuity, and tests diodes via
>   test-leads.

Do you see that the clamp is for AC current measurement. The clamp cannot give a voltage reading. Voltage reading is by the probes.

Comment: I understand that now. And truthfully i did use the probes before for ac voltage on receptacles before i changed then to tamper resistant. Never tried it on wires which i should had read and as you indicated. The clamp meter was originally for testing ac voltage (which i was wrong) and amperage. As i said, i misunderstood the clamp part entirely.  Is there a major difference between trms and rms for my purpose? Or should i had paid a few bucks more and got a true rms? Again thank you. I want to hide my head in the sand. Hope others learn from my mistake.

Comment: For your purposes I doubt there would be any differences between trms and  rms, but I thought you meter read trms? Don't you have the CL600?

Comment: Yes i do have the klein cl600 and truthfully it has helped me especially with continuity and traveler wires (shut off power) utilizing the probes to locating the other set of traveler wires at the other end. It also helped me originally to check my old receptacles using the probes fir determining ac voltage.. I truly do see now that the clamp purpose is only for amperage period which included  utilizing a splitter that i purchase for certain appliances. I found it helpful on the most part except that major screw up with the clamp usage. Again thank you for breaking it down. It says true rms.

Comment: trms as you stated